# unable to get local issuer certificate in Azure VM

Tags: windows, azure-devops, certificate, virtual-machine, agent

[image]

While the node install task is reached pipeline fails with the above error how to resolve this

Answer (score 0):

In the task removed the optional check latest option then it worked

[image]